# Why does my rest-client request raise an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am getting the following error when I make a rest-client request:

```
<internal:D:/softwares/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require': D:/softwares/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-3.1/lib/mime/types/logger.rb:28: _1 is reserved for numbered parameter (SyntaxError)
```

Here is my code:

```rb
require 'rest-client'
response = RestClient.get 'https://www.linkedin.com/feed/'
puts response
```

Can anyone solve this one in return thanks for appreciation?

Comment: `gem install 'rest-client'` ?

Comment: yes i installed the gem,Thanks what next?

Comment: Still not working? What's the error now?

Comment: after the installation of gem i proceeded with following code then i got error like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every require load error execute the below command to install gems for ruby programs.

```
ruby -S gem install <gem-name>
```

in my case it is.

```
ruby -S gem install rest-client
```

Answer (score 2):

You are having a gem versioning issue. The error you are getting when you require `rest-client` is:

```
.../mime-types-3.1/.../logger.rb:28: _1 is reserved for numbered parameter (SyntaxError)
```

This is a problem in the gem `mime-types`, which `rest-client` depends on. Ruby introduced a change in syntax to support 'numbered parameters' in blocks that made `_1, _2, ...` reserved words. That change meant that people who had named variables matching that style (`_1, _2, etc.`) got a warning in Ruby 2.7. In Ruby 3.0 (which you are using), that now causes a syntax error.

The version of `mime-types` you are using (3.1) must have had code of that kind; it worked prior to Ruby 3.0, but now breaks. The good news is that the latest version of `mine-types`, 3.3.1, works with Ruby 3. You just need to update your gem:

```
D:> gem update mime-types
Updating installed gems
Updating mime-types
Fetching mime-types-3.3.1.gem
Successfully installed mime-types-3.3.1
```

If you are using bundler, you might need to change the version in your `Gemfile` and re-rerun `bundle install` to trigger the update.